# Segmentation fault - MPI FFTW

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi, fftw

I have a very simple code of 2D MPI FFTW as follows.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int N0 = 4, N1 = 4;
  fftw_plan plan;
  fftw_complex *data; //local data of course
  ptrdiff_t alloc_local, local_n0, local_0_start;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  fftw_mpi_init();

  int id, p, ierr, count;
  ierr = MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p );
  ierr = MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id );

  /* get local data size and allocate */
  alloc_local = fftw_mpi_local_size_2d(N0, N1, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                       &local_n0, &local_0_start);

  data = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);
  memset( data, 0, alloc_local*sizeof(fftw_complex));
  printf("Processor %d of %d - Local row index starts at %ld with %ld * %d size\n",id,p, local_0_start,local_n0,N1);
  /* create plan for forward DFT */
  plan = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_2d(N0, N1, data, data, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                  FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

  /* initialize data to some function my_function(x,y) */
  count = 0;
  for (int i = local_0_start; i < local_0_start + local_n0; ++i) for (int j = 0; j < N1; ++j){
    data[i*N1 + j][0]=local_0_start;
    data[i*N1 + j][1]=i;
    //printf("Processor %d of %d - (%d,%d) - %d - %f + %f i \n",id,p,i+1,j+1,count,data[i*N1 +j][0],data[i*N1 +j][1]);
    count +=1;
  }

  fftw_execute(plan);
  fftw_destroy_plan(plan);

  fftw_free(data);
  MPI_Finalize();
  printf("finalize\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I compile and run it as

```
mpicc -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib  ${PRJ}.c -o ${PRJ} -lfftw3_mpi -lfftw3 -lm 
mpirun -np 2 ./simple_mpi_example
```

When I try to initialize some data to my data matrix, leads me to a segmentation fault during mpirun on MacOS with error code

```
Processor 1 of 2 - Local row index starts at 2 with 2 * 4 size
Processor 0 of 2 - Local row index starts at 0 with 2 * 4 size
[Sanaths-MacBook-Air:82223] *** Process received signal ***
[Sanaths-MacBook-Air:82223] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[Sanaths-MacBook-Air:82223] Signal code:  (0)
[Sanaths-MacBook-Air:82223] Failing at address: 0x0
[Sanaths-MacBook-Air:82223] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff7d48bb3d _sigtramp + 29
[Sanaths-MacBook-Air:82223] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node Sanaths-MacBook-Air exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault: 11).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
make: *** [run] Error 139
```

I tried to run the same code on a linux machine and it gave an error too as follows.

```
Processor 1 of 2 - Local row index starts at 2 with 2 * 4 size
Processor 0 of 2 - Local row index starts at 0 with 2 * 4 size
double free or corruption (!prev)
[sanath-X550LC:05802] *** Process received signal ***
[sanath-X550LC:05802] Signal: Aborted (6)
[sanath-X550LC:05802] Signal code:  (-6)
^C^CMakefile:7: recipe for target 'run' failed
```

This error occurs only when I am trying to access the data using nested for loops. When I don't do it, it runs without errors. This led me to believe I might be overstepping bounds somewhere, but I am not.

Any suggestions / tips will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your code is based on this [MPI example code](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/2d-MPI-example.html)? The example indicates that each local process processes a *slice* of the whole array:

```c
for (int     i = 0; i < local_n0; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N1;       ++j) {
        data[i*N1 + j][0] = complex_real_part(local_n0_start + i, j);
        data[i*N1 + j][1] = complex_imag_part(local_n0_start + i, j);
    }
}
```

But your code assumes it can access the *whole* array, although you only allocated memory for the local *slice*:

```c
data = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);
memset(data, 0, alloc_local*sizeof(fftw_complex));
...
for (int     i = local_n0; i < local_n0 + local_n0; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0;        j < N1;                  ++j) {
        data[i*N1 + j][0] = complex_real_part(i, j);
        data[i*N1 + j][1] = complex_imag_part(i, j);
    }
}
```